# Python - using a shared variable in a recursive function

Tags: python, recursion, global-variables, return-value

I'm using a recursive function to sort a list in Python, and I want to keep track of the number of sorts/merges as the function continues. However, when I declare/initialize the variable inside the function, it becomes a local variable inside each successive call of the function. If I declare the variable outside the function, the function thinks it doesn't exist (i.e. has no access to it). How can I share this value across different calls of the function?

I tried to use the "global" variable tag inside and outside the function like this:

```
global invcount  ## I tried here, with and without the global tag

def inv_sort (listIn):
    global invcount   ## and here, with and without the global tag

    if (invcount == undefined):  ## can't figure this part out
        invcount = 0

    #do stuff
```

But I cannot figure out how to check for the undefined status of the global variable and give it a value on the first recursion call (because on all successive recursions it should have a value and be defined).

My first thought was to return the variable out of each call of the function, but I can't figure out how to pass two objects out of the function, and I already have to pass the list out for the recursion sort to work. My second attempt to resolve this issue involved me adding the variable `invcount` to the list I'm passing as the last element with an identifier, like `"i27"`. Then I could just check for the presence of the identifier (the letter `i` in this example) in the last element and if present pop() it off at the beginning of the function call and re-add it during the recursion. In practice this is becoming really convoluted and while it may work eventually, I'm wondering if there is a more practical or easier solution.

Is there a way to share a variable without directly passing/returning it?

Comment: What does your function currently return? Does it mutate `listIn` or create and return a new list?

Comment: Well, I guess it returns a new list because I create a new list object to return, but it uses the same elements from the input list and just adds them in sorted order to the new list. You input a list and the function outputs the list in sorted order. I have it outputting the list in order correctly now, but I was just having an issue getting it to count the number of swaps or inversions in the ordering process, which was the actual assignment in my algorithms class.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There's couple of things you can do. Taking your example you should modify it like this:

```
invcount = 0

def inv_sort (listIn):
    global invcount

    invcount += 1

    # do stuff
```

But this approach means that you should zero `invcount` before each call to `inv_sort`.
So actually its better to return `invcount` as a part of result. For example using tuples like this:

```
def inv_sort(listIn):

    #somewhere in your code recursive call
    recursive_result, recursive_invcount = inv_sort(argument)

    # this_call_invcount includes recursive_invcount
    return this_call_result, this_call_invcount
```

Comment: Can I return a list as part of a tuple? For example `return this_list, this_integer`?

Comment: Yes, sure. Any object can be a part of a tuple

Comment: Alright. Also, why exactly does this mean that I would have to zero-out the variable with each function call? I want the running total, and with local variables the value is forcibly reset to default. Are you saying the global variable is reset to 0 with each function call or are you suggesting I do this as best-practice?

Comment: If you want to sort two lists you will have to assign invcount to zero, sort first list, store invcount value in other variable. Then set invcount to zero, sort second list and store its value. Otherwise after sorting two lists you will have sum of function calls for two sorts.

Comment: No, I only want to sort one list at a time. It's actually an implementation of the merge-sort algorithm, so the real code goes something like this: `left = whole[:middle] right = whole [middle:] left = inv_sort(left) right = inv_sort(right)`. I want the `inv_count` to be shared.

Comment: I understand this. Imagine that you've implemented `inv_sort` with global `inccount`. Now you want to use it in actual code. You will do that like this: `invcount=0 inv_sort(list1)`. After this call `invcount` will store the number of merges as you expected. Later in your code you decide to sort another list: `inv_sort(list2)`. But after that command `invcount` will show the sum of number of merges in to sort calls. To prevent this you should do `invcount=0 inv_sort(list2)`. That's why I told you that you should zero `invcount` before each sorting.

Comment: Alright, that's a valid point. I'll put a remark in my code and reset it between discrete sorts (which I will probably be making use of in my testing/debugging/validating results steps after writing the code).

Comment: I tried this out and it's working perfectly on all the test cases I've thrown at it so far. I'm selecting this as the answer since it includes both the easy answer (setting the `invcount = 0` outside the function and then `global invcount` inside) and using the function to return both the sorted list and the count variable. Thanks!

Comment: super awesome. it helps alot

Answer (score 7):

There's no such thing as an "undefined" variable in Python, and you don't need one.

Outside the function, set the variable to 0. Inside the loop, use the `global` keyword, then increment.

```
invcount = 0
def inv_sort (listIn):
    global invcount

    ... do stuff ...

    invcount += 1
```

Comment: So in this case, the inner `global invcount` only reserves the name of my variable in the internal namespace of the function? When I alter it, it will change the value of the outer variable with the same name?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. What `global` does is to tell the interpreter "in the current scope, the name "invcount" refers to the global variable" - so any assignment to that name affects the global variable.

Comment: Ok, that's what I wanted to know. Thanks!

Comment: can the global variable be a list?

Answer (score 5):

An alternative might be using a default argument, e.g.:

```
def inv_sort(listIn, invcount=0):
    ...
    invcount += 1
    ...
    listIn, invcount = inv_sort(listIn, invcount)        
    ...
    return listIn, invcount
```

The downside of this is that your calls get slightly less neat:

```
l, _ = inv_sort(l) # i.e. ignore the second returned parameter
```

But this does mean that `invcount` automatically gets reset each time the function is called with a single argument (and also provides the opportunity to inject a value of `invcount` if necessary for testing: `assert result, 6 == inv_sort(test, 5)`).

Comment: This is an interesting idea. I didn't think about passing *in* the `invcount` variable, only passing it back out. I'll have to play around with it and see how it works.

Comment: Also, you have a comma on the left side of the assignment operator - does this mean I could theoretically return a tuple and have each value of that tuple be assigned automatically to the corresponding variable on the left side?

Comment: @AliumBritt yes, that is precisely what is happening - `invcount` returns a 2-tuple that is unpacked to two separate names e.g. `l` and `_`.

Comment: Ok, I'm going to have to try the function out with that. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you don't need to know the count inside the function, I would approach this using a decorator function:

```
import functools

def count_calls(f):
    @functools.wraps(f)
    def func(*args):
        func.count += 1
        return f(*args)
    func.count = 0
    return func
```

You can now decorate your recursive function:

```
@count_calls
def inv_sort(...):
    ...
```

And check or reset the `count` before or after calling it:

```
inv_sort.count = 0
l = inv_sort(l)
print(inv_sort.count)
```

Comment: So in this situation my inv_sort function would be a sub-function inside the count function? I'm not sure if I understand all the lines in your example. I've never used any function calls or declarations using the `@` symbol. What exactly does using `@` mean/do?

Comment: `@count_calls` is syntactic sugar for `inv_sort = count_calls(inv_sort)` - the "decorator" function (`count_calls`) must take a function as an argument (`f`) and return a function (`func`). `count` isn't a function - it's an attribute of `func`, used to keep track of the number of times `func` is called (and therefore, as `func` calls `f`, how many times `f` is called).

Comment: @AliumBritt note that I just corrected a typo - `count_calls` actually *didn't* `return func`!

Comment: So, is this simply counting the number of times that the function is called? I actually need to know the results of various steps inside the function, so the number of times that I call the function won't be directly related to this value. In fact, I can call the function many times without ever incrementing my internal result variable `invcount`.

Comment: @AliumBritt in that case, this approach probably isn't much use to you!

Comment: Probably not, but I always appreciate learning new tricks in Python, because knowing me there will most likely be a time when I need to know how to do this. Thanks!