# How to carry variable through recursive function in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

I was doing some leetcode problems and found that I couldn't carry my variables through recursive functions as I thought I could.

So for example, say I wanted to sum all of nodes of a tree.

So I thought of implementing it this way:

```
def Sum(root):


    def dfs(root,x):
        if root:
            dfs(root.left, x)
            x.append(root.val)
            dfs(root.right,x)

        return x

    return(sum(dfs(root,x=[])))
```

And this works. However, say I want to cut down on memory, how come this implementation doesn't work and just returns the root node.

```
def Sum(root):


    def dfs(root,x):
        if root:
            dfs(root.left, x)
            x+=(root.val)
            dfs(root.right,x)

        return x

    return(sum(dfs(root,x=0)))
```

Any help or guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python - using a shared variable in a recursive function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23762322/python-using-a-shared-variable-in-a-recursive-function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`x` is mutable in your first definition; each call to `dfs` gets a reference to the same list.

In your second example, `x` is *immutable*. The value of `x` is not modified by the recursive call; `x += root.val` just updates the *local* copy of the argument.

Instead, you need to add the return value of `dfs` directly to `x`.

```
def Sum(root):
    def dfs(root, x):
        if root:
            x += dfs(root.left, x)
            x += root.val
            x += dfs(root.right,x)
        return x

    return dfs(root, x=0)
```

There's no need to define `dfs`, since you aren't really doing a generic search or walk any more. Just call `Sum` recursively. Also, the return value is sufficient; you don't need an `x` argument at all.

```
def Sum(root):
    if not root:
        return 0
    else:
        return Sum(root.left) + root.val + Sum(root.right)
```

Comment: That makes sense to me. Thank you for explaining it so clearly.